# I need showing filter's list

Tags: php, laravel, search, filter

I'm filtering and on my dd($search) shows data, but not my blade

I think it's a return's problem.

```
$req1 = $request->has('searchByStatus');

if ($req1 && $request->input('searchByStatus') === 'open')//same with closed
    { 
        $search = MaintenanceTasks::select(
            'Start_date_reparation'
        )
       ->where('Start_date_reparation','like' ,'1999-11-11 00:00:00')
       ->get();  
       dd($search);
    }

return view('/otList', [
    'searchByStatus'=>$req1,
    'search'=>$search
]);
```

blade.php I summarized it a bit

```
    <select type="text" name="searchByStatus">
            <option value="open">open</option>
            <option value="closed">closed</option>           
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
 @foreach($search as $otList)
 @if(($otList->getDateString() == '1999-11-11 00:00:00'))
                            <label>open</label>
                            @else
                            <label>closed</label>   
                            @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

`dd()` (die and dump) halts execution of your function, so assuming your `if` condition is true, you're not going to be returned to your `view`.

```
if ($req1 && $request->input('searchByStatus') === 'open') { 
    $search = MaintenanceTasks::select('Start_date_reparation')
       ->where('Start_date_reparation','like' ,'1999-11-11 00:00:00')
       ->get();  

       // this is preventing the rest of your function executing
       dd($search);
}
```

You could use `dump($search);` instead which is similar but won't prevent the rest of your function executing.

Comment: well but it's showing the same black chart, i need it shows me on a list

Comment: @Tatiana Can you add your blade code to your question?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your `foreach` loop? You have a conditional in there which might be preventing anything being output on the page.